# Problem with .sort() method in Javascript, two arrays sort instead of only one

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, methods

I'm trying to define an array `b` to be an independent copy of an array argument `a`. 
Thus, I want to change `b` without changing `a`.

But here is a mystery: When I sort `b`, `a` is sorted as well!

```
function firstDuplicate(a) {
    let b = a;

    console.log(`this is a : ${a}`)  // this is a : 2,1,3,5,3,2 
    console.log(`this is b : ${b}`)  // this is b : 2,1,3,5,3,2

    b.sort()                    
    console.log(`this is a : ${a}`)  // this is a : 1,2,2,3,3,5 (my problem)
    console.log(`this is b : ${b}`)  // this is b : 1,2,2,3,3,5
}

firstDuplicate([2, 1, 3, 5, 3, 2])
```

How can I avoid this?

Thank you so much for your replies.

Comment: they share the reference, try copying the array and sort, it's not a problem with the sort().

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy array by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copy-array-by-value)

Comment: It happens because of 'shallow copy'. `let b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a));` Would do very deep copy. Actually, created a new instance of the same information...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't duplicating `a`, you're just creating a new reference to it. Copy the array with `slice()`, then sort it.

```js
let b = a.slice().sort();
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are stored by reference in javascript, so when you do

```
 let b = a
```

You’re not duplicating, you’re just setting b and a to point at the same array. This would work:

```
 let b = [...a]
```

This declares a new array and uses the spread operator to fill it with the contents of a

But be careful because if objects or arrays are inside your original array, the two different arrays are still pointing at the same objects or arrays.

Answer (score 0):

by doing

```
let a = b;
```

you are copying the reference, so any change made to the either of the array will reflect in the other array.

here you have to do a copy,

```
let a = [...b];
```

But using the spread operator to copy the array will create a shallow copy, if you want to do a deep copy of the array.

```
let a = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(b));
```

and then perform sort on it

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, in Javascript the line `let b = a` is essentially saying make `b` point to the same array as `a`. This is because Arrays are stored by reference. As a result any modifications made to `a` will also be applied to `b`.

The solution is to create a new array and let `b` point to this. This can be done multiple ways

```
let b = Array.from(a)
let b = [...a]
let b = a.slice().join('')
```

Each of these returns a new Array rather than a reference to the original.

To prove this you could run the following

```
let a = [1,2,3];
let b = a;
let c = Array.from(a);

a === b  // true
a === c  // false (because it is a new value)

a[2] = 'new';   // [1,'new',3]

a === b // true (because b also points to [1,'new',3])
a === c // false (c still equals [1,2,3] and is still pointing to a different value)
```